# Непонятные отступы у текста сверху и снизу (не margin)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, отступы

Доброй ночи, уважаемые коллеги!

Потихоньку начинаю осваивать верстку и вопрос в следующем - когда мы используем тег с текстом внутри, например `h1`, то у него по умолчанию выставляются небольшие отступы сверху и снизу (не `margin`). Я подозреваю, что это - высота строки, и, наверно, это место предназначено для всяких символов с заковырками снизу или сверху, верно?

Допустим если я сделаю `font-size: 24px` у заголовка `h1`, высота строки тоже будет `24px` или чуть больше?

При профессиональный верстке эти отступы убирают или их не трогают?

Comment: Высота строки - это line-height. Отступы сверху и снизу - это padding.

Comment: вам знакомо понятие межстрочного интервала (из Word'a к примеру)?

Comment: @labris нет, это не падинги, там буквально пару пикселей сверху и снизу и изменение падингов никак на них не влияют.

Comment: @teran т.е. эти небольшие отступы предназначены для создания межстроч. интервала?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верно, если просто - то место сверху и снизу предназначено для заковырок :)

В вебе есть понятие **высота строки** (`line-height`). Оно же - интерлиньяж, оно же - межстрочный интервал. И текст вписывается в строки с такими вот высотами.

Вы можете задавать `line-height` в стилях. Например, в пикселях (`24px`), или в емах (`1.25em`), или в безразмерной величине (`1.2`). Задать для всех элементов (`* {}`), или для каких-то конкретных (`h1 {}`).

Если ничего не задать - будут применены высоты строк по умолчанию. В разных браузерах - разные умолчания.

> Конкретно для `line-height` - в браузерах по умолчанию применяется значение `normal`. Оно означает, что браузер может принимать решение о размере строки самостоятельно. Как правило, оно будет в диапазоне 1.1 - 1.25, но стандарт не гарантирует этого, он говорит лишь, что оно должно быть «разумным» (дословно – англ. reasonable).
>
> Источник цитаты: [Свойства "font-size" и "line-height"](https://learn.javascript.ru/font-size-line-height).

Обычно умолчания сбрасывают, например с помощью [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), и устанавливают свои размеры шрифтов и высоты строк. Иными словами - правила типографики.

Поиграться с этими правилами можно, например, на [gridlover.net](https://www.gridlover.net/try) - подвигайте ползунки, и отметьте кнопку `GRID`, чтобы увидеть сетку. Там же вы можете взять готовый CSS для вашего сайта с необходимыми правилами типографики.

Comment: Допустим я не трогал стили и не использовал нормалайз.
Тег h1 которому я задал размер 24px, в эти 24px уже включены эти небольшие отступы сверху и снизу или получится 24px размер текста + 1-2 пикселя сверху и снизу и в итоге получится что этот блок высотой вышел 26-28px?

Comment: @TemTik, дополнил ответ. По умолчанию браузер сам принимает решение о высоте строки. Например в моем текущем Google Chrome оно равно 1.15. То есть высота строки у меня по умолчанию - в 1.15 раза больше размера шрифта. Отсюда и вытекает пара пикселей сверху и снизу.

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку, оказалась оч полезна, за ответ тоже большое спасибо)